# cannot import name 'inv' from 'numpy.linalg' (unknown location)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
```

The error show up when I import matplotlib.animation
I tried to reinstall numpy  scipy and matplotlib, but it didn't work

```
environment list  
    -torch=1.12.1  
    --numpy=1.23.4  
    --scipy=1.9.2  
    --networkx=2.8.7  
    --matplotlib=3.6.1  
    --dgl=0.5.1
```

Comment: Just restart the Laptop/Pc...It maybe some cache issues..I've encountered import issues with `matplotlib` many times .. Just re-installing/ restarting laptop would fix the issues.

Comment: I reboot my Laptop,but it doesn't work....

Comment: what happens when you `import matplotlib` on its own ?

Comment: the same error.

Comment: Try doing same in virtual Environment..Create a vittual Environmnet & install requiremnts file inside it

Comment: i am already using anaconda virtual env .

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem yesterday, and I found out that the error didn't only occur in matplotlib, but actually in other packages (at least for me). So I figured out that the error was from numpy. I just uninstalled numpy and installed it again:

```
pip uninstall -y numpy
pip install numpy
```

Hope it works for you!